# Importing django model methods in json

Tags: django, json, serialization, models

I am trying to output a set of database records in JSON as follows:

```
def json_dbtable(request, p):

    t = MyModel.objects.filter({some query})
    s = serializers.get_serializer("json")()

    re = s.serialize(t, ensure_ascii=False)

    return HttpResponse(re, mimetype="application/json")
```

However, one of the fields i'm trying to return needs to change if it is `null`, and to remedy this the model has a definition that is used as a property .e.g:

```
name = property(_get_useful_name)
```

So, to get to the crux of the question. How can I include this "name" property in my json serialization as well as the raw field data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, the long answer, is you could serialize your `MyModel` instance yourself:

```
simplejson.dumps([{'pk': m.pk, 'name': m.name} for m in MyModel.objects.filter(...)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a serialization framework for Python called [any2any](https://bitbucket.org/sebpiq/any2any/)
which include [(de)serializers for Django](http://readthedocs.org/docs/any2any/en/latest/doc_pages/djangocast.html)
and which allows you to do [that](http://readthedocs.org/docs/any2any/en/latest/doc_pages/djangocast.html#adding-virtual-attributes-to-the-output) easily.
It will be way cleaner than the DIY way.
Hope that helps !